# Where can one find the total amount of EOS staked on the network?

Tags: stake

What is the total amount of EOS staked on the network? And when its staked its locked up right? So the remaining EOS can be seen as just sitting on the exchanges? Is there a way to find this number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the total amount of EOS staked on the network?

You can check the balance of `eosio.stake` e.g.

```
$ cleos get account eosio.stake
```

> So the remaining EOS can be seen as just sitting on the exchanges?

No, the remaining EOS is unstaked EOS. Exchanges don't need to influence the amount of staked coins: exchanges may offer an option for their users to stake, and users who don't use exchanges may prefer to keep their EOS unstaked for liquidity needs.

Comment: so the *eosio.stake* is a real account itself? What if you accidentally sent eos to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can see it on these sites:

https://eosflare.io

https://eosauthority.com/voting